# How should i make method in father class determine is type base on subclass's method in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I have a code like this.

```js
class Base{
   private getData(): Data | undefined{
        return undefined
   }
   public get output(): Data | undefined {
        return {
             data: this.getData()
        }
   }
}
class A extends Base{
    private getData(){
        return getDatasFromOutside()
    }
    //......
}
class B extends Base{
   //......
}
let x = new A()
let x2 = new B()
x.output.data // I want this can be think as type Data
x2.output.data // while this still is undefined
```

As you can see, typescript think `x.output.data` is `Data | undefined` but it actually is just `Data`.

How to fix this？

Or I should just stop make A and B share the same base class?

Comment: What type does `getDatasFromOutside` return?

Comment: getDatasFromOutside return Data

Answer (score 0):

You can use some generics to represent this:

```
abstract class Base {
  public getData(): Data | undefined {
    return undefined
  }
  getOutput<D>(this: {getData(): D}): { data: D } {
    return {
      // ... other outputs
      data: this.getData()
    };
  }
}
class A extends Base {
  public getData(): Data {
    return getDatasFromOutside()
  }
}
let x = new A()
x.getOutput().data // getOutput<Data>(this: A): Data
```

<sup>([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UB2BXAtgIwgJygDIoBvKASwGcAuKAcgBME56oBfAbgFgAoAMwxoAxsAoB7NFADmEYPERUAYvnFYA8hmBUKjCAAoAlHQVJSfKFGAALVQHd0EBwFF8q-PoBESoaIlS0cWBKLDAAGwgsCDRgCEYAOk9DHl52Pj44HCpgfDhRKGEwuCoqKAAhYuhzXkswDBwwimEZOVMjExYoAB8oIT1+CjQ4sgtLKHw5DHwpPogBocZRtJqW4E1gOuAAHhgAPn0bajpSWXkWdth2YzIoZkQTDhGVywngKalqsbGAem+oeIBUCC1gIQK0myooy+dzgdEOVHipzahihHBSlmWy0KxVKAEEoBAAB6xNCMUoVKhVUZ1BpNVbIjqIJ5fV7veksZSqDRaHR6IxLPjLCLBQkoRwOXH83iExFydabIzxGFAA))</sup>

However, this has some limitations:

- the `getData` method needs to be `public` to count as part of the type
- the `output` getter must be a method, since TypeScript does not support generics or `this` types on accessor property declarations

A better alternative would be an abstract base class with two implementations:

```
abstract class Base<D = undefined> {
  protected abstract getData(): D;
  public get output(): { data: D } {
    return {
      // ... other outputs
      data: this.getData()
    };
  }
}
class A extends Base<undefined> {
  protected getData() {
    return undefined;
  }
}
class B extends Base<Data> {
  protected getData() {
    return getDatasFromOutside()
  }
}
let x = new B()
x.output.data // Data
```

<sup>([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIghsOUC8UB2BXAtgIwgJygDIoBvKASwGcAuKAcgBME56oBfAbgFgAoAMwxoAxsAoB7NFADmEYPERUAYvnFYA8hmBUKjCAAoAlHQVJSfKFGAALVQHd0EBwFF8q-PoBESoaIlS0cWBKLDAAGwgsCDRgCEYAOk9DHl52Pj44HCpgfDhRKGEwuCoqKAAhYogAHhgUKCE9fgo0OIA+MgsoMFVY0TioTOzc-Nl5FiMTFMswDBwwimEZOShxLRngCbIoZkQTDg7eS0t8OQx8KXNDo8sAehuoeMeVmwIVta0qTuuduDobanio1MRi+HCmHD4aV4hWKpQAglAIAAPWJoRilCpUaoNCBNFqMdqXaY9CB9RhLMaIIwHa4nYBnKQ4vFxcFQqEwkrlREo6Lo8qVGosQmdbpBUmxclA8aGGlHOkMimmZSqDQfXQGQydNl8CLBJF1FoOMog3hI+KrYDreI-IA))</sup>

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to declare the method as

```
abstract protected getData(): Data;
```

in the `Base` class, then also make the `output` getter return `Data` and never `undefined`.

Comment: But i want any sub class of `Base`'s `output.data` is `undefined` if it didn't overwrite `getData` function and is `Data` if it overwrite it and return a `Data` value. In another way, i want sub class of `Base` has a optional `getData` methods and it return undefined by default.

Comment: @饕餮饗食 That was not really clear from your question. Could you please [edit it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74037261/edit) to include this detail?